# Error creating an RPM

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I've seen many similar issues dotted around this site but none of the seem to fit the problem I'm faced with.  I've never created an RPM before so I'm completely new to the procedure.  Basically, all I require is a single file created under /etc/yum.repos.d on CentOS.  I have a bare bones spec file which I've put together as follows:

```
Name:      cloud.repo
Version:   1.0
Release:   0
Summary:   Configuration for yum.cloud.local
Group:     System/Base
License:   None
URL:       None
Source0:   cloud.repo
BuildArch: noarch
Prefix :   /etc/yum.repos.d

%description
This package contains the yum.cloud.local repository

%install
%{__install} -m 600 %{SOURCE0} %{buildroot}/etc/yum.repos.d/

%files
/etc/yum.repo.d/cloud.repo

%changelog
```

I then run the following command:

```
$ rpmbuild -ba SPECS/yum.cloud
```

Which subsequently fails with the following:

```
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.AUmyZc
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ '[' /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/xchangingcloud.repo-1.0-0.x86_64     '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/xchangingcloud.repo-1.0-0.x86_64
++ dirname /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/xchangingcloud.repo-1.0- 0.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/xchangingcloud.repo-1.0-0.x86_64
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ /usr/bin/install -m 600     /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/SOURCES/xchangingcloud.repo     /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/xchangingcloud.repo-1.0-    0.x86_64/etc/yum.repos.d/
/usr/bin/install: target    `/home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/xchangingcloud.repo-1.0-  0.x86_64/etc/yum.repos.d/' is not a directory: No such file or directory       error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.AUmyZc (%install)

RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.AUmyZc (%install)
```

I think I can see why this is failing unfortunately I don't have enough knowleage to be able to resolve it.  I can see that the error is complaining about *is not a directory: No such file or directory* and I'm assuming that */home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/cloud.repo-1.0-0.x86_64/etc/yum.repos.d/* needs to be present however, I just know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/yum.repos.d/
```